# Disk [google-drive] does not have a configured driver

Tags: laravel, google-drive-api, laravel-storage, laravel-filesystem

Hi i am trying to link google drive api to the laravel system for what i have used google drive api in laravel and configured the filesystem and env setting. But when executed it returns DISK not configured error.

Tried solution of clearing config cache and dump-autoload still the isuue persist same.

filesystem.php

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

    'google-drive' => [
        'driver' => 'google',
        'clientId' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'clientSecret' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'refreshToken' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_REFRESH_TOKEN'),
        'folderId' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID'),
    ],

],
```

googledriveserviceprovider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
        Storage::extend('google-drive', function($app, $config) {
            $client = new \Google_Client();
            $client->setClientId($config['clientId']);
            $client->setClientSecret($config['clientSecret']);
            $client->refreshToken($config['refreshToken']);
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($config['refreshToken']);
            $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
            $adapter = new   \Hypweb\Flysystem\GoogleDrive\GoogleDriveAdapter($service, $config['folderId']);

            return new \League\Flysystem\Filesystem($adapter);
        }); 
        
    }
```

Route to put file.

```
Route::get('put', function() {
            Storage::disk('google-drive')->put('test.txt', 'Hello World');
            return 'File was saved to Google Drive';
        });
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is the line that giving you `DISK not configured error`?

Comment: Route part return the error

Comment: Didnt you already ask this question? Why open a new one why not continue on your existing qeustion? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63112749/1841839

Comment: Yes the question is well structured here. overthere it was bit clumsy to explain

Comment: did you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line:

```
Storage::extend('google-drive', function($app, $config) {
```

should just be

```
Storage::extend('google', function($app, $config) {
```

Comment: Nope it doesnt help in any how

Answer (score 0):

I think this useful for you

filesystem.php

```
'disks' => [
    'google' => [
        'driver' => 'google',
        'clientId' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'clientSecret' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'refreshToken' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_REFRESH_TOKEN'),
        'folderId' => env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID'),
    ],

],
```

googledriveserviceprovider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
        Storage::extend('google', function($app, $config) {
            $client = new \Google_Client();
            $client->setClientId($config['clientId']);
            $client->setClientSecret($config['clientSecret']);
            $client->refreshToken($config['refreshToken']);
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($config['refreshToken']);
            $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
            $adapter = new   \Hypweb\Flysystem\GoogleDrive\GoogleDriveAdapter($service, $config['folderId']);

            return new \League\Flysystem\Filesystem($adapter);
        }); 
        
    }
```

Route file

```
Route::get('put', function() {
            Storage::disk('google')->put('test.txt', 'Hello World');
            return 'File was saved to Google Drive';
        });
```